# Polynomial function residues

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruence-relations

If we use Euclid's representation for integers $n=aq+r$, we can write $n\equiv r \mod q$.

We can also write functions similarly, for example $n(x)=a(x)q(x)+r(x)$ and so I imagine we can write $n(x)\equiv r(x)\mod q(x)$.

There are loads of theorems using the arithmetic modular, for example Wilson, Euler and Fermat. Are there any known theorems for the functional modular?

(I am thinking of the associate $b$ of a given $a$ such that $ab\equiv 1\mod p$)

Comment: Normally $q,q(x)$ denote quotients, so you would write $n\equiv r\,\pmod{\! a}$ and $n(x)\equiv r(x)\,\pmod{\! a(x)}$ instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your "functions" are polynomials over the integers, you're talking about the commutative rings $\mathbb Z[x]/\langle q[x]\rangle$.  Yes, a lot is known about these.